# VBA - #VALUE error during initial run , multiplier to dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, error-handling, multiplication

I apologize for the confusing title but to start, I created some code to apply a multiplier (a defined variable referenced to a cell value) to a dynamic range of non-blank/non-empty cells but only in certain columns and am running into a #VALUE error ALWAYS at the beginning of the code running and not after.

**Background**

There is a userform that gets filled out by a user(s) and part of this form allows inputting a multiplier that will be applied to a single ws's dynamic table that a user is working on. The overall table can vary in size (column-wise) and the column header names will change from ws to ws. This "multiplier" needs to only update filled cells in certain columns, so this is not a multi-ws task/update, just whenever it's completed by a user.

Overall, the columns that need to be updated from ws to ws can be grouped into 3 based on a partial text match: " *Rate", " *Amount", " *Factor". There are over 10 total column headers that partially match these.

---

**Issue**

The thing I haven't been able to resolve is that when using the macro the first time on a new sheet, it gives #VALUE errors in random blank cells (doing the math right for the filled cells in the certain columns). But after that initial run/after clearing contents manually and re-running the code, it updates the applicable cells without any issue.

[Before code ran: table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGv8G.png)

[After code ran: Resulting #VALUE error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTllB.png)

---

**My Code**

```
Option Explicit

'1) Rate multiplier obt from Rate Diff form & stored in Admin ws (See: Rate form)

'----------------------------------------------
'2) Apply rate mutliplier 
'----------------------------------------------

Sub IP_Rate_Multiplier()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim LC As Long
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim multiplier As Double
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    multiplier = wb.Sheets("Admin").Range("U2").Value
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    'Applic cols: "*Rate", "*Amount", "*Factor"
    
    LC = ws.Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column      'hdr row count/length
    
    For c = 7 To LC                                           'Loop from col 7 to last col
        If ws.Cells(6, c).Value Like ("*Rate*") Or ws.Cells(6, c).Value Like ("*Amount*") Or ws.Cells(6, c).Value Like ("*Factor*") Then
            LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row        'Last row of ea. col
            For r = 7 To LR                                   'Loop from row 7 to last row
                If ws.Cells(r, c) <> "" Then
                    ws.Cells(r, c).Value = Evaluate(ws.Cells(r, c).Value() & "*" & multiplier)
                End If
            Next r
        Else
        End If
    Next c
           
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

---

So I'm not absolutely certain if this is related to improper(or lack of) error handling, incorrect code above, or due to the fact that it's a new ws that is always populated in the wb and then worked on?

If there is anything else I can provide, please let me know!

---

**Edit**

To clarify some of the code/code comments above: This multiplier happens only at a specific time. The userform that is filled out also informs other things that go into the ws and it is unknown when or what will be inputted by a user so I can't make this a ws change event.

Comment: I would guess your "blank" cells are not actually blank. So clearing the range resolves the problem.

Comment: I didn't have any formulas in these cells but there is VBA ws_change events code & VBA dv code tied to these cells. I performed a .ClearContents on the affected range before running the code and it worked! TY so much, that was such a simple solution!